# West of Loathing, Jumbleneck Mine -- how to detonate the cart

Tags: west-of-loathing

I have put the dynamite in the cart, and I know how to detach the cart from the mechanism it gets attached to. But how do I make it hit the rocks hard enough to blow them up?

Answer (score 2):

To detonate the cart, you have to change the track so that it runs into the rocks as opposed to the cart stopper. Then with the unstable dynamite in the cart, simply use the spring lever to launch the cart into the pile of rocks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you switch the tracks back so that they point to the pile of rocks again once the cart is attached to the spring lever mechanism.

Comment: That's literally what my answer says.